# How would you stop a variable from resetting every time a for-loop runs?

Tags: python, for-loop

I am trying to make a number classifier in python. This classifier is intended to determine whether the inputted integer is odd or even, and whether it is prime or not. In the `primesorter(userin)` function, I have a for-loop which loops through every number following up to the inputted number, with each loop returning the remainder of the division between the user input and `x`. If the remainder is == 1, then a variable `isnotprime` is `+=` added to.

In the program, I tried to make it so that when this variable reaches over `2`, it will print `f"{userin} is not a prime number"`. Instead, I see that every instance of the loop it resets this variable. How can I make it save?

```
# Importing the time module to allow slight delay
from time import sleep

# Have to put sorting function first to avoid referencing error
def sorter(userin):
    if (userin%2) == 0: # Returns remainder: if its 0, the number is even 
        sleep(0.5)
        print(f"{userin} is an even number")
        sleep(0.5)

    elif (userin%2) > 0: # Returns remainder: if its greater than 0, the number is odd
        sleep(0.5)
        print(f"{userin} is an odd number")
        sleep(0.5)

def primesorter(userin):
    for x in range(1,userin):
        isnotprime = 0 # «« This variable will not save every instance of the loop. 

        if (userin%x) == 1:
            isnotprime += 1
        print(isnotprime)
        
        if isnotprime >= 2:
             print(f"{userin} is not prime")
        else: print(f"{userin} is prime")

# Ask user for input
userin = int(input("Input a number to be categorized: "))


# Enter user input into the pre-defined function
sorter(userin)
primesorter(userin)
```

Comment: You need to move `isnotprime = 0` outside of the `for` loop. As written it is the first statement that is executed on each loop.

Comment: Thank You! This tip was successful and helped me complete the program!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable definition needs to be outside the for loop, otherwise each time you do an iteration the variable is reset.
for example:

```
input_var = 0 # variable defined outside the for loop
for i in range(12):
    input_var+=1 # this line executes every loop
    # input_var = 0 # if it's defined here every loop would initialize the variable to zero
    print(input_var)
```